# No Display in Design Layout android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

**ERROR TEXT**

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show  sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or  descendant) with the design library.   at  android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init> (CoordinatorLayout.java:206)   at  android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:200)   at   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)   at  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385) Copy stack to  clipboard
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your style like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
...
</style>
```